# Display AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display a simple dialog with android, but it crashes at start.

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog();
        Dialog dialog = messageDialog.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

MessageDialog.java :

```
public class MessageDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage("Hello World").setPositiveButton("0K", null);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.*****.*****, PID: 7458
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.*****.*****/com.example.*****.*****.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources$Theme
>   android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling "onCreateDialog"?

Use the following code to show a dialog fragment:

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_name");
```

(The second parameter is the tag for the fragment. It can be used to get the fragment via "FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag" later.)

Comment: because I thought it was like this :)